# Explain how this reduce() generates all sub-lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering how this expression works.

```
f = lambda l: reduce(lambda z, x: z + [y + [x] for y in z], l, [[]])
```

How this function creates the subset of all the number in an array which is passed to it.

output:

```
f([10,9,1])

[[], [10], [9], [10, 9], [1], [10, 1], [9, 1], [10, 9, 1]]
```

Comment: Break it down... do you understand `[y + [x] for y in z]`? `reduce()` is building a list, and aggregates into `[[]]`, the starting empty list, and that is mapped to `z`. `x` is the next element to be collected

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the lambdas to functions, use some better variable names, and print a few things, you should be able to follow the logic:

```
def f(xs):
    results = [[]]
    return reduce(g, xs, results)

def g(results, x):
    results_with_x = [r + [x] for r in results]
    combined = results + results_with_x
    print('-----')
    print('r ', results)
    print('x ', x)
    print('rx', results_with_x)
    print('c ', combined)
    return combined

def main():
    xs = [10, 9, 1]
    results = f(xs)
    print('-----')
    print('  ', results)

main()
```

Output:

```
-----
r  [[]]
x  10
rx [[10]]
c  [[], [10]]
-----
r  [[], [10]]
x  9
rx [[9], [10, 9]]
c  [[], [10], [9], [10, 9]]
-----
r  [[], [10], [9], [10, 9]]
x  1
rx [[1], [10, 1], [9, 1], [10, 9, 1]]
c  [[], [10], [9], [10, 9], [1], [10, 1], [9, 1], [10, 9, 1]]
-----
   [[], [10], [9], [10, 9], [1], [10, 1], [9, 1], [10, 9, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

We call lambda function stored in f variable with arg = [10, 9, 1]
Short description about what happening:

```
reduce(lambda z, x: z + [y + [x]] for y in z, [10,9,1], [[]])
# inside reduce in short description:
it = [10,9,1]
accum_value = [[]]
for x in it:
    # accum_value = lambda z,x: z + [y + [x]] for y in z
    # where z = "accum_value" and x = element of "it" iterable. 
    # There this lambda calling each time of cycle with new params.

    # first in: 
    # accum_value = [[]] + [[]+[10]] = [[], [10]]

    # second in: 
    # accum_value = [[], [10]] + [[]+[9]]+[[10]+[9]] = [[], [10], [9], [9,10]]

    # third in: 
    # accum_value = [[], [10], [9], [9,10]] + [[]+[1]] + [[10]+[1]] + [[9]+[1]] + 
    # [[9,10]+[1]] = [[], [10], [9], [10, 9], [1], [10, 1], [9, 1], [10, 9, 1]]

return accum_value
```

so, that return [[], [10], [9], [10, 9], [1], [10, 1], [9, 1], [10, 9, 1]]